# Type error while constructing an Array

Tags: haskell, types

I'm trying to memoize this function with an array:

```
a n 0 = n
a n k = a (2*n - 1) (k - 1) / a (2*n) (k - 1)
```

I've done this:

```
import Data.Array

cache :: (Ix a, Real b) => Array a [(a, b)]
cache = array bounds [(i, func i) | i <- range bounds]
    where bounds = ((0,0), (1000, 1000))
          func elem =
            let f n 0 = n
                f n k = f (2*n - 1) (k - 1) / f (2*n) (k - 1)
             in uncurry f elem

a n k = cache!(n,k)
```

GHCi fails with this error:

```
aarr.hs:6:16:
    Could not deduce (a ~ ([(a, b)], b0))
    from the context (Ix a, Real b)
      bound by the type signature for
                 values :: (Ix a, Real b) => Array a [(a, b)]
      at aarr.hs:5:11-44
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for values :: (Ix a, Real b) => Array a [(a, b)]
          at aarr.hs:5:11
    Expected type: (a, a)
      Actual type: (([(a, b)], b0), ([(a, b)], b0))
    Relevant bindings include
      bounds :: (([(a, b)], b0), ([(a, b)], b0)) (bound at aarr.hs:7:11)
      values :: Array a [(a, b)] (bound at aarr.hs:6:1)
    In the first argument of ‘array’, namely ‘bounds’
    In the expression: array bounds [(i, func i) | i <- range bounds]
```

My head is spinning from all the type errors (and infinite type ones) I got... I thought this could work.

Comment: The type of `range` is `range :: Ix a => (a, a) -> [a]` and you're giving it `((a,a),(a,a))`.

Read the last 2 lines of ghci's output: `In the first argument of ‘array’, namely ‘bounds’
    In the expression: array bounds [(i, func i) | i <- range bounds]`

Comment: But in GHCi this works: `Prelude Data.Array> range ((0, 0), (3, 3))      
[(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,0),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,0),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)]`. I think `(0, 0)` is an instance of `Ix` too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The Problem

There are two problems with your your `cache` function which are preventing it from compiling.

The first is that the type of `(/)` is as follows,

```
(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a
```

However the compiler is inferring the values in your `bounds` as `Integral` types, which is doesn't jive with your use of `/`.

The second is that your type signature is incorrect.

## A Solution

There are a number of ways to correct this, but probably the simplest is the following,

```
cache :: (Ix b, Fractional b) => Array (b, b) b
cache = array bounds [(i, func i) | i <- range bounds]
    where bounds = ((0.0,0.0), (1000.0, 1000.0))
          func elem =
            let f n 0 = n
                f n k = f (2*n - 1) (k - 1) / f (2*n) (k - 1)
             in uncurry f elem
```

Notice that the values of `bounds` are now `Fractional` values.

Also notice that I changed your type signature. The first type parameter to `Array` needs to be the `Ix` instance. Since you are using `Fractional` pairs as the indices this needs to be reflected in the type. Secondly, this also means that the values of the element in the array, shares the same type as the index. If you wish to have you index be an Integral value, then you could do the following,

```
cache :: (Integral a, Ix a, Fractional b) => Array (a, a) b
cache = array bounds [(i, func i) | i <- range bounds]
    where bounds = ((0,0), (1000, 1000))
          func (a, b) =
            let f n 0 = n
                f n k = f (2*n - 1) (k - 1) / f (2*n) (k - 1)
             in uncurry f (fromIntegral a, fromIntegral b)
```

Note, I don't know if using an `Integral` type vs. a `Fractional` type as the index has any performance considerations as I don't use the `Array` type very often.

Comment: Wow, thank you for taking the time to write this. I now see the problems with my code. I'll check Map as well, or try to solve the recursion. Just one thing: shouldn't `(\)` be `(/)`? Thanks again!

Comment: It should. Good catch.

Comment: I may be incorrect about the strictness of the `Array`. I was just reading the documentation for it and it claims, "Because the indices must be checked for these errors, array is strict in the bounds argument and in the indices of the association list, but non-strict in the values." Which means it would have to fully compute the bounds and indices but not the values.